# How to make Smooth Scrolling?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

This is my horizontal adapter.

```java
recyclerViewyeterr=findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewyeterr);

LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(GYUserSahaDetay.this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

recyclerViewyeterr.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);

gYresimadaptor=new GYresimadaptor(resimler2);

recyclerViewyeterr.setAdapter(gYresimadaptor);
```

And XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GYresimadaptor">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to make smooth scrolling with a horizontal layout. How can ı do that?

Thanks,